# Why doesn't tmux respond to shortcuts properly?

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, zsh, tmux, iterm2

I'm using OSX 10.8.1 in combination with iTerm2, zsh and tmux via Homebrew.

The beginning of my ~/.tmux.conf file looks like this:

```
set -g prefix C-a
unbind C-b
bind-key a send-prefix
set -sg escape-time 1
```

When I start tmux and press **C-a c**, nothing happens.
When I spam **C-a c** fast enough then some new tabs open up, but not the equivalent count of my command spaming. When I press **C-a** first followed by **c**, nothing happens again. Is there a delay issue or what's up with my tmux installation/configuration?

Comment: I'm using iTerm2, MacPorts' tmux & bash, but it shouldn't really matter; what you have should work regardless of bash vs. zsh and, in theory, Homebrew vs. MacPorts.  I can only guess that there's something wrong with Homebrew's tmux...

Comment: The strange thing is, a friend of mine is using Homebrew's tmux and it is working fine. But I'm going to try another tmux installation, just for testing.

Comment: You could try to get rid of the escape-time; it didn't cause any problems with my tmux, but I'm not sure that it's needed and it's possible that it could be getting in the way, somehow.

Comment: I just put it into my config to test it. It doesn't matter if it is in my config or not, the issue persists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use "[tmux2](https://github.com/gnachman/tmux2)", which has iTerm2 integration. As you're using Homebrew, this will work:

```
[ kill/quit all running tmux sessions ]

$ brew tap adamv/alt

$ brew remove tmux   # Repeat this until you get an
                     # error to clean everything out

$ brew install tmux-iterm2
```

Then, open an iTerm2 window and type `tmux -C` to begin.

Comment: I just reinstalled iTerm2 and replaced the stable version with the beta one. Don't know if the beta release fixed the issue or just a reinstall of iTerm2 did that, but everything works fine now. No need of tmux integration of iTerm2. Btw there is no "tmux-iterm2" brew formula. Nevertheless, thanks for your answer!

Comment: There is, **in the `adamv/alt` (homebrew-alt) tap**.

Answer (score 2):

Do you press C-a and THEN c?  In screen, you can do C-a THEN c OR C-a+c.  I usually use the later and that one is not working for me and I'm quite disappointed...